# If $X$ is compact and $T:X \to Y$ continuous and bijective, show that $T$ is homeomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, $X$ compact, and $T:X \to Y$ bijective and continuous. Show that $T$ is a homeomorphism.

My attempt:

We need only show that $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

Let $M \subset Y$ be closed. Then, from the surjectiveness of $T$, there exists a $A \subset X$ such that $T(A)=M$. Since $M$ is closed, by the continuity of $T$, we must have that $A$ is closed.

Now $$T^{-1}(T(A))=T^{-1}(M)$$ i.e, $A=T^{-1}(M)$. Since $A$ and $M$ are closed, we must have that $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

My problem with this, however, is that I am not using the fact that $X$ is compact anywhere in the proof. Is there perhaps another way that I can show this, using the compactness of $X$?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: You should start with a closed $N\subseteq X$, not $M\subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand your argument (see Arthur's comment).

Now, to show that $T^{-1}$ is continuous, we show that $T$ maps closed set to closed set (do you see why it's equivalent?). Let $A\subset X$ be closed. Since $X$ is compact, $A$ is also compact. Thus $T(A)$ is also compact. And a compact subset of a metric space is closed.

Comment: You do not need a metric: let $U_a$, $a\in I $ be an open cover of $T (A) $, continuity implies  $T^{-1}(U_a) $ is an open cover of $A $. Compactness gives us a finite cover...

Comment: You do need something though;  Consider $X=Y=\{a,b\}$, $X$ is given its power set as topology while the topology on $Y$ is $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. The identity map $T:X\to Y$ is bijective and continuous but its inverse is not continuous.

On the positive side, if $Y$ is Hausdorff then each of its compact subsets is closed, and the assertion holds.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Sure, I meant the argument for knowing that  $T (A) $ is compact. Also, in your case, $X$ is not compact since it is the union of all one-point sets.